# Can't reset rotation at all

Tags: transforms

I have a rather big problem with how my Blender works

Out of the blue, I'm now not able to rotate any object in blender in any file, even totally fresh ones.

I validated files through Steam, I redownloaded the program, I even reinstalled my addons, yet it won't work.

Does anyone have any ideas to why such a thing happens?

For the record, I'm using 2.93 on Steam

[image]

Comment: could you please share one of your objects? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots Done

Comment: ok weird because I can rotate and reset the rotation of your object here so there must be a bug somewhere, or have you checked your shortcuts?

Comment: I checked them and also I did reset them to their factory settings. Still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have Affect Only Origins or Locations set in the tool properties:

[image]

Comment: None of these were selected, sadly.

Comment: How are you trying to rotate the objects? With R, or with Rotate tool(shift+space - > Rotate)?

Comment: I use the R button